# Every abelian $p$-group is the direct product of cyclic groups.

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, abelian-groups, p-groups, direct-product

**Theorem** $:$ Every abelian $p$-group is the direct product of cyclic groups.

I have started reading that proof from this [Proof Wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Abelian_Group_of_Prime-power_Order_is_Product_of_Cyclic_Groups) article. Here I have understood everything before the element $b$ is introduced. Actually I can't understand what's the definition of $b$ mentioned in this article. Can anybody please make it clear to me?

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: @Shaun I think I got my answer. Would you please take a look at my answer?

Comment: It looks okay to me, @mathmaniac.

Comment: Thanks for your verification @Shaun. But one another problem arises there. How do they say $\left | G / \left \langle a \right \rangle \right | = p^{n-1}$? That means $\left |\left \langle b \right \rangle \right | = p$ i.e. $\left |b \right | = p.$ That means they are assuming that there are more than $\varphi(p)=p-1$ many elements in $G$ of order $p.$

Comment: @Shaun is it true that if I take any non-cyclic abelian $p$-group $G$ then it will have more than $p-1$ elements of order $p$?

Comment: You're welcome, @mathmaniac. I'm not sure how to answer your follow-up questions though.

Comment: If we keep a dialogue going here, an option to discuss things in a chatroom will appear, @mathmaniac.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101560/discussion-between-math-maniac-and-shaun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need only to take any element $b \in G \setminus \left \langle a \right \rangle$ which has the minimal order amongst all the elements of $G \setminus \left \langle a \right \rangle.$ Then it will have the required property as mentioned in the article of the link.