# Any finite non-cyclic abelian $p$-group will have more than $p-1$ elements of order $p.$

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, abelian-groups, p-groups

Any finite non-cyclic abelian $p$-group will have more than $p-1$ elements of order $p.$

This question came into my mind while I was discussing to Shaun about a question I have just posted [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3453251/598690)  Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is an infinite Abelian $p$-group with exactly $p-1$ elements of order $p$.

Comment: No I am talking about finite abelian $p$-groups @Lord Shark the Unknown. I have edited my question accordingly. Now I think it's ok.

Comment: This follows quickly from the classification of finite(ly generated) abelian groups—more specifically the invariant factor decomposition (or, equivalently for $p$-groups, the primary decomposition).

Comment: Actually I am trying to prove **Structure Theorem for Finitely Generated Abelian Groups** with the help of the theorem in the link I have provided. For proving the linked theorem I need to prove this theorem. So I cannot assume **Structure Theorem** here in order to prove this theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the basic theorem you can write $G=C_1\times C_2\times\dots$ where $C_i$ are cyclic abelian $p$-groups. Since $G$ is not cyclic, there are at least two factors. Each factor has at least $p-1$ elements of order $p$. [If a generator is $a$ and the order is $p^n$, then take powers of $a^{p^{n-1}}$.]

----------- Added later

From the comment below, you don't want to use the structure theorem.

Take $C$ to be a cyclic subgroup of maximum possible order. As above, there are certainly at least $p-1$ elements of order $p$ in $C$.

Now take an element $x\in G\setminus C$ of smallest possible order. $x^p$ has smaller order than $x$, so $x^p\in C$. If $x^p$ generated $C$, then $x$ would be a larger cyclic subgroup than $C$ (contradicting the maximality of $C$). So $x^p$ must be a $p$th power in $C$, ie we can find $y\in C$ st $x^p=y^p$. Hence $xy^{-1}$ has order $p$ and does not belong to $C$. That gives us at least $p-1$ elements order $p$ outside $C$.

Comment: Actually I am trying to prove **Structure Theorem for Finitely Generated Abelian Groups** with the help of the theorem in the link I have provided. For proving the linked theorem I need to prove this theorem. So I cannot assume **Structure Theorem** here in order to prove this theorem. It will be better if you can able to provide an independent proof of this theorem which does not require any knowledge of **Structure Theorem**.

Comment: @mathmaniac. I have added some additional material to avoid using the Structure Thm.

Comment: Very nice answer. +1.